# Ajax response in a text field

Tags: ajax

I have this ajax form that gets the value of the user field, I need the answer of everything of all the process I do in the php file to be seen in the same user field but it doesn't work how can I do this thanks

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="button" />
</form>
```

```
$.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                    
           data: $("#form").serialize(),
           success: function(data)            {
             $('#user').html(data);  //print answer in text field         
           }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `val()` method to set text in an textbox

```
$.ajax({                        
   type: "POST",                 
   url: url,                    
   data: $("#form").serialize(),
   success: function(data)            {
      $('#user').val(data);  //print answer in text field         
   }
});
```